# Are launch schedules coordinated internationally?

Tags: launch

[Slightly related](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5018/how-are-space-agencies-coordinating-their-science-missions-internationally).  I am not looking for general coordination, simply on dates and times of non-related launches.

---

With up to almost daily launches into space, is there (A) any coordination between space-faring countries regarding schedule, and (B) any need for coordination on schedules (e.g. - they may simply have no impact on each other)?

Comment: See second part of [How are multiple launches handled?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/2080/49)